# Getting JSON data with an API route that has many pages

Tags: java, android, api, android-asynctask

I'm getting pretty familiar with using Asyn tasks to fetch data from API endpoints now. I can easily hit a url and parse the JSON data that returns.

However I've run into a problem in which this API has a lot of pages to it.

What's the best way to deal with an API that has a lot of pages, and has no option to change the results per page?

My particular endpoint has 40+ pages of data (12 results per page). I feel as if spinning up a new async task per each page endpoint is a bit ridiculous.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need 40+ API calls to get the data of the 40+ pages. There is no way to trick the server to return more pages at once if its API doesn't support it.

Comment: Retrofit would have less code

Comment: I figured.. but is there a best practice to making 300+ api calls? I have a few different endpoints I need to get data from, and each endpoint has 40+ pages.

Comment: You can make all the call's inside one Async task.

Comment: @Mehdi could you link me an example maybe? Thanks

Comment: something like:
class MyTask extends Async<....> {
 doInBackground() {
 for (int i = 0 -> 40)  { appendResult(callService()); }
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly as everyone suggest there is no way around the api if it does not support a results per page argument. You could prefetch one or two pages and join them in one AsyncTask that way you minimize the amount of async task that fork from the main thread and have a strategy when you need to load more pages.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest you, use retrofit HTTP client. I had the same issue almost 260+ calls and Retrofit work fine for me.[Check it here](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)